# use a for loop or lapply to iterate through different dataframes in a list in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

I apologize if this question seems rudimentary. I'm a bit unclear on if it's possible / how to use for loops with a list of data frames in R.

I have dataframes that are subsets of a larger dataframe:

```
billysuzy <- subset(userlist,user1 %in% c("billy","suzy"))
joefrank<- subset(userlist,user1 %in% c("joe","frank"))
georgelenny <- subset(userlist,user1 %in% c("george","lenny"))
```

I would like to loop through and find correlation values for the same variables (time and simscore) for each subset.

```
cor(time, simscore)
```

However, I am quite uncertain how to structure such a for loop and unsure how to structure a function to attach and detach within lapply.

I was thinking:

```
somelist <- list(billysuzy, joefrank, georgelenny)
```

with lapply:

```
corz <-  lapply(somelist, function(df)  detach(), attach(df),cor(time, simscore))
lapply(corz, print)
```

or with for:

```
for (i in 1:length(somelist)){
      detach()
     attach(somelist[i])
    cor(time, simscore)
    }
```

I apologize for offending anyone's R sensibilities or if the seems like two questions - the answer is any which describes how to do the one thing i.e. loop through the dfs in the list and find there corr values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would really recommend avoiding `attach` and `detach`.

You could try something like this

```
corz <-  lapply(somelist, function(df)  cor_time_sim = cor(df$time, df$simscore))
```

Or

```
corz <-  lapply(somelist, function(DF)  {with(DF, corst <-  cor(time, simscore))})
```

Or

```
corz <-  lapply(somelist, with, corst <-  cor(time, simscore))
```

Comment: Setting the variable cor_time_sim caused the error message: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : argument is missing, with no default". I dropped it and just used cor and it worked great. Thank you.

Comment: See my two edits, it was due to using `=` not `<-` for assignment.